# Problemas al realizar deploy en Azure de aplicacion Angular, despliega version desactualizada

Tags: angular, azure, deployment

He intentado realizar el despliegue a traves de VS Code y de la herramienta Kudu interna a los AppService de Azure.

El problema es que se despliega una versión de la app anterior a la actual. Por lo tanto si realizo el despliegue y cargo la página en local se ve de manera distinta a la desplegada.

He actualizado Angular CLI a la versión estable más reciente pero el comando ng build --prod (o ng build) en ambos casos crea una carpeta dist desactualizada, por lo tanto tengo distintas versiones respecto al despliegue y respecto a la versión en local.

¿Alguno os ha ocurrido este issue con anterioridad?

Mis pasos son:

1. Ejecuto comando ng build (--prod)
2. Entro en herramienta Kudu, inserto dist.zip en site\wwwroot
3. Ejecuto comando ng build (--prod)
4. Realizo deployment a través de VS Code (Inicio sesión, elijo AppService y realizo deployment).

En ambos casos recibo este login:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debería recibir este, el que ejecuto en localhost:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede ser problema de chache?. Inténtalo con una ventana de incognito o limpia la cache del navegador para descartar.

Comment: Me siento súper inútil jeje Tenías toda la razón, problema del propio navegador al abrirlo en una ventana de incognito me cargó correctamente la info 

Muchas gracias @Legna =)

Si lo añades como respuesta la indico como correcta asi ganas puntitos ;)

Comment: Es un problema muy común en desarrolló web. A poco te acostumbraras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser problema de chache?. Inténtalo con una ventana de incognito o limpia la cache del navegador para descartar.

## [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)

> El almacenamiento en caché o Caching es una técnica que almacena una copia de un recurso dado y la devuelve cuando se solicita. Cuando un caché web tiene un recurso solicitado en su almacén, intercepta la solicitud y devuelve su copia en lugar de volver a descargarla desde el servidor de origen. Esto logra varios objetivos: facilita la carga del servidor que no necesita atender a todos los clientes, y mejora el rendimiento al estar más cerca del cliente, es decir, lleva menos tiempo transmitir el recurso de vuelta. Para un sitio web, es un componente importante para lograr un alto rendimiento. Por otro lado, debe configurarse correctamente, ya que no todos los recursos permanecen idénticos para siempre: es importante almacenar en caché un recurso solo hasta que cambie, no más.

Para resolver este problema en el deployment puedes usar el siguiente comando:

`ng build --prod --aot --outputHashing=all`

A esta técnica se le llama [Cache-busting](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting) y lo que hace es crear un identificador único para todos los archivos que se generen. Con esto logras engañar al navegador y descargar las nuevas versiones de tus archivos.

Las opciones son :

- none: No se realiza el hashing
- media: solo agrega hashes a los archivos procesados via url|file
- bundles: solo agrega hashes a las salida de los bundles.
- all: agrega hashes a ambos, media y bundles.

Tomado de [está respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment)