# Porque mi proyecto de angular a veces no muestra los cambios que hago cuando despliego a producción

Tags: angular, angular7, angular6, angular8, angular9

He notado ya varias veces que cuando estoy en desarrollo los cambios que voy haciendo los veo en el navegador de forma instantánea (uso Chrome), pero cuando me toca subir mi proyecto a un host de producción estos cambios no los veo reflejados, me toca borrar el cache de la pagina o probar en incógnito para así poder verlos, ¿a que se debe este comportamiento?

Comment: Dependen de varias cosas, como estas compilando tu proyecto? y a que servidor-web lo estas cargando?

Comment: Revisa si [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/427314/33391) resuelve tu duda.

Comment: Lo compilo con los comandos de angular por ejemplo ng build ---prod y el host esta en los servicios de microsoft azure

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que la pagina ya esta precargada en el caché y por eso debes eliminar el caché para ver los cambios, es totalmente normal.
Saludos.